# Add event to cascade update

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I'm using fluent NHinernate in my application with cascade all option.

I have a complex model with a bunch of entities and relations in it. Everything is held by one entity (Contract) it has some collections of other entities. These entities have references to other entities / lists of entities.

When I want to save the whole thing I just do this:

```
mySession.Save(myContract);
myTransaction.Commit()
```

Works fine, saves all the entities thanks to cascade.

The problem is that I need to set properties ModifiedBy, ModifiedTime, etc on update. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create an interface for the properties you need to update:

```
public interface IAudit
{
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
}
```

And then add an `NHibernateInterceptor` to update the properties:

```
public class AuditInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {
        var auditableEntity = entity as IAudit;
        if (auditableEntity != null)
        {
            auditableEntity.ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now;
            // ...
        }

        return base.OnSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
// ...
}
```

You then need to tell NHibernate to use the interceptor which if I remember correctly is done as follows:

```
var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession(new AuditInterceptor());
```

Depending on how you manage your sessions etc will depend where this goes, and since `AuditInterceptor` has no state it could exist as a singleton without worry of multi threading issues.

Comment: Is it possible do determine if the entity is being saved or updated?

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of other methods you can override depending on whether the entity is new or dirty.

Comment: When I used this Interceptor - cascade no longer automatically sets foreign keys. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: What version of NHibernate are you using? I haven't used it for a while, this is similar to what I did previously but that was on version 2. Not sure why this would interfere with foreign keys though.

Comment: I'm using version: 3.3.1.4000, runtime version: v2.0.50727

Comment: @gisek sorry, I'm not sure why this might cause cascade to not set foreign keys.

Comment: Ok. It turned out the problem was in my program, not i nhibernate.